# Compile Overleaf project offline referencing figures by their labels

Tags: latex, tex

I have a LaTeX project created in Overleaf that I would like to be able to work on and compile offline.  I've downloaded MacTex and have been trying to use TeXShop to do this, but am running into problems with it not recognizing the labels of .png and .jpg figures that I defined into my online Overleaf projects.

Example of creating figure:

```
\graphicspath{ {[path to figure]}}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{figure.jpg}
    \caption{the figure caption}
    \label{fig:Figure label}
\end{figure}
```

Calling figure to reference it by Figure #:

```
Figure\,\ref{fig:Figure label}
```

Error:
LaTeX Warning: Reference 'fig:Figure label' on page [page above command is on] undefined on input line [line above command is on]

If anyone knows how to fix this it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Not just the snippet of the code for figure.

Comment: Don't use spaces in labels